# How can I render HTML tags inside textarea in angular forms

Tags: javascript, html

I have an angular reactive form in which I have a textarea field named Acceptance Criteria.

What want to achieve is written below :

When I edit the Acceptance Criteria field with the below text :

Example :   **My content**     and click on Save, the value of the field gets updated to the new one.

But actually I only want the text in bold while viewing the field's content.

I should see only **My content**.

Note : Any tags can be there in the HTML control named Acceptance Criteria.

Comment: If your control renders as an actual `textarea` HTML element, then this element can display and edit only plain text, HTML tags can be displayed in this element only as the HTML source code. To have editable text with working HTML markup in it, you have to use something like the Rich Text editor or WYSIWYG editor component, based on the `contenteditable` property, instead of `textarea`

Comment: can you please give me an example.